# C++ friend classes and friend member functions

Tags: c++, class, friend

I'm learning about friend functions, friend classes and friend member functions in C++ classes;
Now, the following code compiles fine:

```
#include <iostream>

class A 
{
public:
    friend class B;
    //friend void B::set(int i);
    //friend int B::get();
    friend int function(A a);
    A(int i);
    void set(int i);
    int get();
private:
    int i;
};

A::A(int i) : i(i)
{
}

void A::set(int i)
{
    this->i = i;
}

int A::get()
{
    return i;
}

class B
{
public:
    B(A a);
    void set(int i);
    int get();
private:
    A a;
};

B::B(A a) : a(a)
{
}

void B::set(int i)
{
    a.i = i;
}

int B::get()
{
    return a.i;
}

int function(A a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a(0);
    std::cout << "in A i=" << a.get() << std::endl;
    a.set(10);
    std::cout << "in A i=" << a.get() << std::endl;
    B b(a);
    std::cout << "in B i=" << b.get() << std::endl;
    b.set(21);
    std::cout << "in B i=" << b.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "function returns " << function(a) << std::endl;
}

int function(A a)
{
    return a.i;
}
```

I am able to grant friendship to class B and to function "function" in class A without forward declaring class B, or function "function". 
Now, if I want to grant friendship to the two member functions in class B it doesn't work if I don't define class B before defining class A:

```
#include <iostream>

class B;   // doesn't work, incomplete type (complete type needed)

class A 
{
public:
    //friend class B;
    friend void B::set(int i);
    friend int B::get();
    friend int function(A a);
    A(int i);
    void set(int i);
    int get();
private:
    int i;
};

A::A(int i) : i(i)
{
}

void A::set(int i)
{
    this->i = i;
}

int A::get()
{
    return i;
}

B::B(A a) : a(a)
{
}

void B::set(int i)
{
    a.i = i;
}

int B::get()
{
    return a.i;
}

int function(A a);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    A a(0);
    std::cout << "in A i=" << a.get() << std::endl;
    a.set(10);
    std::cout << "in A i=" << a.get() << std::endl;
    B b(a);
    std::cout << "in B i=" << b.get() << std::endl;
    b.set(21);
    std::cout << "in B i=" << b.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "function returns " << function(a) << std::endl;
}

int function(A a)
{
    return a.i;
}
```

but I can't define class B before defining class A so I'm stuck. Forward declaring (not defining) class B doesn't work either.

So my questions are:

1) why I dont need to forward declare a function or an entire class in a friendship declaration but I do need to define a class if I need to specify member functions of that class?
I know that friendship declarations are not declarations in the common sense (they just grant access, they don't forward declare anything).

2) how can I make my code compile (besides declaring the A member object in B as A *a)?

Comment: In fact there is no need to declare the member functions of the class B as friend functions because the class A has public interface.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it is indeed a contrived example. I just want to understand why it does not work and how I can get around that.

Comment: "I can't define class B before defining class A" why?

Comment: @Luca It does not work because the compiler does not know whether the class B indeed has these member functions.

Comment: @n.m. The definition of the class B contains a data member of the type class A that shall be a complete type.

Comment: Ah yes I see now

Comment: It doesn't actually make much sense to have friend member functions. Just make the entire class a friend.

Comment: @n.m. actually it does make sense

Comment: Class is a small enough unit of privilege granting. Sure you could use more fine-grained access and sometimes it's nice but this doesn't make or break your design. Bad things won't happen if you just make the entire class a friend.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a friend class and how to use it. This was taken [cplusplus.com](http://cplusplus) The reason I am posting this is because your example does not really illustrate the proper use of friendship in c++. I hope this will shed some light as to how/why you should use friendship, and that can lead to you solving your forward declaration problems.

```
// friend class
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Square;

class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    int area ()
      {return (width * height);}
    void convert (Square a);
};

class Square {
  friend class Rectangle;
  private:
    int side;
  public:
    Square (int a) : side(a) {}
};

void Rectangle::convert (Square a) {
  width = a.side;
  height = a.side;
}

int main () {
  Rectangle rect;
  Square sqr (4);
  rect.convert(sqr);
  cout << rect.area();
  return 0;
}
```

> In this example, class Rectangle is a friend of class Square allowing
>   Rectangle's member functions to access private and protected members
>   of Square. More concretely, Rectangle accesses the member variable
>   Square::side, which describes the side of the square.
>
> There is something else new in this example: at the beginning of the
>   program, there is an empty declaration of class Square. This is
>   necessary because class Rectangle uses Square (as a parameter in
>   member convert), and Square uses Rectangle (declaring it a friend).
>
> Friendships are never corresponded unless specified: In our example,
>   Rectangle is considered a friend class by Square, but Square is not
>   considered a friend by Rectangle. Therefore, the member functions of
>   Rectangle can access the protected and private members of Square but
>   not the other way around. Of course, Square could also be declared
>   friend of Rectangle, if needed, granting such an access.
>
> Another property of friendships is that they are not transitive: The
>   friend of a friend is not considered a friend unless explicitly
>   specified.

Answer (score 0):

Just make `class B` a friend of `class A`. There are no adverse effects in doing this.

If you absolutely positively want to exercise more fine-grained control, you can do it with a proxy class like this (using your example stripped to bare bones):

```
class Proxy;

class A
{
public:
    friend class Proxy;
    A(int i);
private:
    int i;
};

class B
{
public:
    B(A a);
    void set(int i);
    int get();
private:
    A a;
};

class Proxy
{
  friend void B::set(int);
  friend int B::get();
  static int& get_i(A& a) { return a.i; }
  static const int& get_i(const A& a) { return a.i; }
};
```

You now can use `Proxy::get_i(a)` instead of `a.i` in `B::set` and `B::get` (only).

Comment: in this case I don't even need the Proxy class forward declaration